# Work with active Intellij files programmatically (java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am looking for java solution for the following scenario.

***I need to get titles of all active files in Intellij IDE (also its content if possible) in my java application. Firstly, my java application run Intellij IDE (runtime.exec()). Later, I need to list active files of this Intellij instance.***

I found **com.intellij.openapi library** for creating plugins. But it doesn't seem to be a proper solution. I dont want to use plugin.xml, just library. If I use [openfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/openfiles)  command, I would see all files, not only active (and my app will work only on windows OS). I have found **PlatformUi** from Eclipse which seems to do what am I looking for, but I need Intellij solution. **COM objects** may be solution too, maybe.

Do you have some experience with this topic?

EDIT:
I tried following code. Now I need to access active files opened within this process (IDE IntelliJ).

```
public Process launchApplicationProcess() throws IOException {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec(this.applicationPath);

        return process;
    }
```

I also tried com.intellij.openapi. Within this library I need to use plugin.xml to get IntelliJ instance, then I can accomplish my scenario. But I dont want to use plugin.xml. I just need IntelliJ instance from java class. Following code still returns NULL, because I dont use plugin.xml.

```
Application app = ApplicationManager.getApplication();
```

**Is there a way to get IntelliJ instance from java class?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. What have you tried already? You need to be more precise. If you read [ask] it will suggest that you include an example of your efforts

Comment: For the IntelliJ IDEA API and plugins approach take a look at http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html